# Numpy genfromtxt() skip invalid lines

Tags: python, numpy

I am using Numpy's genfromtxt() function to get large amounts of txt data as array.
The data is provided in following format:

```
2020-05-20 16:54:01.807645  1033.074    2392.555    256.8516    2700.547    1029.691    2108.094    3256.539    90.94727    1775.043    4.770321    48.875
```

The log file also contains lines like the following:

```
2020-05-20 17:05:21.864533  DUT stopped
```

I want to skip those lines. Is there a way of doing so?

My current approach:

```
values = np.genfromtxt(fi, dtype="S32,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8", missing_values='', delimiter="\t", invalid_raise=False, filling_values=0)
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt) you can also pass in a generator generating bytestrings (lines) to `np.genfromtxt()`.

> **fname**
>
> - file, str, pathlib.Path, list of str, generator
>
> File, filename, list, or generator to read. If the filename extension is gz or bz2, the file is first decompressed. Note that generators must return byte strings. The strings in a list or produced by a generator are treated as lines.

```
def skip_stopped_lines(fi):
    for line in fi:
        if b"DUT stopped" in line:
            # Don't yield this line, we don't want it
            continue
        yield line


# NB: not using `with` to avoid the file being closed
#     while the generators are active

fi = open("somefile.txt", "rb")  # note binary mode
skipper = skip_stopped_lines(fi)
values = np.genfromtxt(
    skipper,
    dtype="S32,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8",
    missing_values="",
    delimiter="\t",
    invalid_raise=False,
    filling_values=0,
)
```

might do the trick for you.